# Multiple minimal models in R forward stepwise regression

Tags: r, regression

In R stepwise forward regression, I would like to specify several minimal models. I am looking for the best model whith choices between 12 variables (6 flow variables Q_ and 6 precipitation variables LE_).

Biggest model takes into account all the variables :

```
formule <- "Q ~ 0 + Q_minus_1h + Q_minus_2h + Q_minus_3h + Q_minus_4h + Q_minus_5h + Q_minus_6h + LE_6h + LE_12h + LE_18h + LE_24h + LE_30h + LE_36h"
biggest <- formula(lm(formule, Sub_fit))
```

With Sub_fit my set of data (data frame with Q and my 12 variables).

I would like to have at least one variable "LE_XX" in my model. So my minimal model could be :

```
formule <- "Q ~ 0 + LE_6h"
smallest <- formula(lm(formule, Sub_fit))
```

OR

```
formule <- "Q ~ 0 + LE_12h"
smallest <- formula(lm(formule, Sub_fit))
```

OR...

```
formule <- "Q ~ 0 + LE_36h"
smallest <- formula(lm(formule, Sub_fit))
```

With finally :

```
modele.res <- step(lm(as.formula("Q ~ 0"),data=Sub_fit), direction='forward', scope=list(lower=smallest, upper=biggest))
```

"lower", into "scope", does not allow a list but should be one unique formula. Is it possible to do what I need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify several minimal models in stepwise forward regression, create the smallest formulas with, for instance, `lapply` and then loop through them.
In the example below, built-in data set `mtcars` is used to fit several models having `mpg` as response, one per each of the 3 last variables in the data set.

```
data(mtcars)

biggest <- mpg ~ .

sml <- names(mtcars)[9:11]
small_list <- lapply(sml, function(x) {
  fmla <- paste("mpg", x, sep = "~")
  as.formula(fmla)
})
names(small_list) <- sml

fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars)
fit_list <- lapply(small_list, function(smallest){
  step(fit, scope = list(lower = smallest, upper = biggest))  
})
```

Now select with AIC as criterion

```
min_aic <- sapply(fit_list, AIC)
min_aic
#      am     gear     carb 
#154.1194 155.9852 154.5631

fit_list[[which.min(min_aic)]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Your example works well with data mtcars. If I try with my own data, with lower = "Q ~LE6h" I got the following error : Error in factor.scope(ffac, list(add = fadd, drop = fdrop)) : lower scope has term 'LE_6h' not included in model. It does not work with any "LE_X" variable but it works with "Q_minus_1h" variable. Do you know what it could be ?

Comment: I got it ! The first argument of the function step (fit in your example) should be coherent with the smallest model asked. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Chika Yes, that's it, `mpg ~ .` is a formula with `mpg` as a response and all other variables (the dot `.`) as regressors. This is the model fitted and then the loop will `step` down to `smallest`.

Answer (score 0):

stepwise function in ***StepReg*** R package can include some variables you want in all models during the stepwise regression.

```
library(StepReg)
f1 <- Q ~ 0 + Q_minus_1h + Q_minus_2h + Q_minus_3h + Q_minus_4h + Q_minus_5h + Q_minus_6h + LE_6h + LE_12h + LE_18h + LE_24h + LE_30h + LE_36h

## include LE_6h in the model
stepwise(formula=f1,
         data=yourdata,
         include="LE_6h",
         selection="forward",
         select="AIC")

## include LE_6h and LE_12h in the model
stepwise(formula=f1,
         data=yourdata,
         include=c("LE_6h","LE_12h"),
         selection="forward",
         select="AIC")
```